# How do connect /var/www/html folder to the spring-boot project in /home/user

Tags: apache2

I have created a spring-boot project in /home/MYUSERNAME folder
in the spring boot project there are html and jsp files in webapps/jsps/ folder.
So, how do I link them to www/html folder?

Is it a good way to do it ?

Comment: This is not an ubuntu question, I would ask on stackoverflow

Comment: Yeah, since I was trying to do this in an ubuntu server, thought I should ask this here

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with a symbolic link?

```
usage: ln [-Ffhinsv] source_file [target_file]
       ln [-Ffhinsv] source_file ... target_dir
       link source_file target_file
```

Example

```
ln -s /home/MYUSERNAME/PROJECT_NAME/webapps/jsps/ /var/www/html
```

If destination folder already exists, you have to delete it